# type hint a object that implements interface not the class

Tags: php, oop

In PHP 5.3 > can I type hint a object with interface?

Like so:

```
public function AddToFavorite(Trendmed\Interfaces\Favoriteable $entity) {}
```

or Im only limited to checking implementation inside function? I've tried to type hint like above and it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> PHP 5 introduces type hinting. Functions are now able to force
>   parameters to be objects (by specifying the name of the class in the
>   function prototype), **interfaces**, arrays (since PHP 5.1) or callable
>   (since PHP 5.4)

So it could use interfaces.

Comment: Maybe Im doing something wront but Im getting an error: AddToFavorite::AddToFavorite() must be an instance of Trendmed\Interfaces\Favoriteable, instance of Proxy\__CG__\Trendmed\Entity\Clinic given

Comment: I think it's beacose Doctrine2 makes those proxy classes with does not directly implement my interface. Bugger.

Comment: @BartoszRychlicki So it means the type hint works, you are passing wrong type :)